# Can I pull this low voltage mounting bracket out?

Tags: electrical, mounting

So my builder put in a low voltage mounting bracket, and I want to pull the thing out to put in a [Powerbridge](https://www.powerbridgesolution.com/) unit.

Does anyone know if I can just pull out the mounting bracket, or is it screwed into the stud somewhere? 
[image: low voltage mounting bracket]

Answer (score 2):

Mine are screwed into a stud. It looks like there are coax cables in there and this plate is the access point. There some other cables in there too, might be alarm cables. I'd put a cover over this and mount your powerbridge somewhere else.

Comment: As implied by Jack, that is not an "electrical power" box, because there is no actual box, so it is limited to "low voltage" circuits such as coax cables, communications wires (network etc.) and alarms. You cannot run power wires into it and/or make connections in there. Pulling it out and replacing it with an electric box will entail significant damage and subsequent repair to the wallboard, plus you might STILL need someplace for your cable / network connections (although with wireless, that's becoming less common). I would just add a new box for power and close this one as suggested.

Comment: thanks, there is a cable conduit in there for hdmi cables and such, was hoping to reduce the number of holes cut into the wall, but will take your advice and start a new one for the powerbridge